# Why Grid is needed predetermined background?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-animation

I made in style a button animation. All elements of a button placed in the Grid. But if do not set background in grid, animation does not work correctly.

Button:

```
<Grid>
  <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
    Margin="5">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="RotateTransform" 
            Angle="0"/>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
  </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Animation:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>

<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateTransform"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                RepeatBehavior="Forever" 
                Duration="0:0:0.3" 
                To="60"/>
            <!--360 / 6 (number of gear teeth on the image) = 60-->
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>

<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateTransform"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                Duration="0:0:0.2"
                To="0"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Grid without a background:

https://habrastorage.org/files/152/b26/179/152b26179cbb43c4b03e93357501df18.gif

Grid with background:

https://habrastorage.org/files/b55/6aa/831/b556aa8315bb4bfdb5f2a0e1f0810dae.gif

Why is this happening?

Comment: Because without `Background` area of the `Grid` is not hit test visible so `MouseEnter`/`MouseLeave` will appear only on part of your content and not whole `Grid`. You can initialize it with Transparent, which will have same visual effect as default null, but will make whole `Grid` area hit test visible

Comment: I believe you should add this as answer

Comment: Yes, but I do not understand how to set as a solution to a comment (yes, I was a newbie on stackoverflow). So we had to write my answer and mark it as the answer.
PS: now I can not mark my answer as a solution, shows a message that "You can accept your own answer tomorrow". Okey...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [dkozl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1432140/dkozl) for answer:

> Because without Background area of the Grid is not hit test visible so MouseEnter/MouseLeave will appear only on part of your content and not whole Grid. You can initialize it with Transparent, which will have same visual effect as default null, but will make whole Grid area hit test visible

So, solution is to set a transparent background:

```
<Grid Background="#00000000"><!--Transparent background-->
   <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
              Margin="5">
      <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
         <RotateTransform x:Name="RotateTransform" 
                          Angle="0"/>
   </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
  </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```